# Duplicate transaction with same nonce

Tags: transactions

Need some expert to provide guidance.. Did an ETH transaction and it was a success.. Suddenly, there was a duplicate transaction (exact same transaction) with the same nonce appearing..

[image: Duplicate transaction with same nonce]

On Etherscan, the duplicate transaction status is showing as Pending.. However, when you drilled into tx, its status is showing as Success

[image: Drilled in of 2nd transaction - Success Status]

As the duplicate transaction is "pending", I am not unable to send the last transaction as it kept showing there is a pending account nonce

[image: Last transaction which is stuck due to lower account nonce]

Can anyone advice how do I remove the duplicate pending 2nd transaction so that my latest transaction can process.. Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is an etherscan bug.

If transaction 0x506d was included in a block, any other transaction from the same address and the same nonce is void. It should not prevent you to send another transaction with nonce + 1.